# How i can spy constructor functions calls in my angular test?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have one service that in `constructor()` makes a subscribe and calls a function:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
      if (e instanceof RouterEvent) {
        this.closeModal();
      }
});
```

In my test i tried:

```
describe('ModalService', () => {
   let service: ModalService;
   beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: routeStub,
        },
      ],
    });
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    service = TestBed.get(ModalService);

  fit('should close modal when is a instance of RouterEvent', async () => {
    spyOn(service, 'closeModal');
    await router.navigate(['/']);
    expect(service.closeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

})
```

My routerStub:

```
export const routeStub = (): Partial<Router> => {
  const events = of(new RouterEvent(1, 'test'));
  return {
    events,
    navigate: (commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) => {
      return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => resolve(true));
    },
  };
};
```

when i put a `console.log('test')` inside my `closeModal()`, my message `test` is being printed, but my expect aways return error with the message:

> Expected spy closeModal to have been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Problem

The constructor method is called when the component is created, so by the time you are testing it, it was already executed. This is why the test fails but the console log shows that method was called

### Solution

You need to spy on the class component `prototype` instance

```typescript
fit('should close modal when is a instance of RouterEvent', async () => {
    
    const closeModalSpy = spyOn(AppComponent.prototype, 'closeModal').and.callThrough()
    TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(closeModalSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()

  });
```

I have tested the above and it works
[image]